# SystemException with LogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, logarithmic-scale

In plotting a function with specific set of parameters using `LogLinearPlot`, *Mathematica* throws a `SystemException[MemoryAllocationFailure]` error. It works on occasion with other values of parameters, and always when simple `Plot` or `LogPlot` is used. Do you have any suggestions?

```
f[x_] = b + (a - b)/(1 + (x/c)^d);
setGood = {a->1417, b->52.2, c->9.68*10^16, d->0.68};
setErr = {a->1360, b->92, c->1.3*10^17, d->0.91};

LogLinearPlot[f[x]/.setGood, {x, 10^13, 10^20}](* works *)
LogLinearPlot[f[x]/.setErr, {x, 10^13, 10^20}](* throws error! *)

Plot[f[x]/.setErr, {x, 10^13, 10^20}](* works *)
LogPlot[f[x]/.setErr, {x, 10^13, 10^20}](* works *)
Plot[f[10^x]/.setErr, {x, 13, 20}](* works *)
```

PS: on Mathematica 11.1.1.0, using Windows 10 (64-bit)

Comment: For what it's worth, no error is thrown on 10.1 and `LogLinearPlot` plots fine.

Comment: same for 11.0.1.0 OSX

Comment: On mac, I don't see the issue on 11.0.1, but I do see it on 11.1. I've reported it.

Comment: + no issue on v9.01 on Windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With V11.1.1 running on OS X 10.10.2, I didn't get an error message, I got a kernel crash. A work-around is simply to change `b` from an exact number to a machine float.

```
Clear[a, b, c, d]
f[x_] := b + (a - b)/(1 + (x/c)^d)
setFix = {a -> 1360, b -> 92., c -> 1.3*10^17, d -> 0.91};
LogLinearPlot[f[x] /. setFix, {x, 10^13, 10^20}]
```

[image: plot]